# How to know when bracket satisfies Jacobi identity

Tags: lie-algebras

I am working through *Introduction to Lie Algebras* by Erdmann and Wildon. Frequently, when determining a Lie algebra in the text, the authors will give a basis (say $\{x,y,z\}$) and then fix the bracket on all permutations of the basis (say $[x,y] = y, [x,z] = y + z, [y,z] = 0$) and then state that a Lie algebra has been formed.
My question is: how can we know that any such bracket defined is actually a Lie bracket? I suppose any arbitrarily defined such bracket (say $[x,y] = a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 z, [x,z] = a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2 z, [y,z] = a_3 x + b_3 y + c_3 z$) will be bilinear, and alternating is presupposed.
Thus, my question can be rephrased: is there any way to see if such an arbitrarily constructed bracket satisfies the Jacobi identity other than by testing every possibility? I feel like there must be a faster way as Erdmann and Wildon never seem to verify this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a vector space basis $(e_1,\ldots ,e_n)$ and Lie brackets
$$
[e_i,e_j]=\sum_{r=1}^n c_{ij}^r e_r,
$$
the Jacobi identity is equivalent to the system of polynomial equations
$$
\sum_{r=1}^n (c_{ij}^r c_{lr}^s+c_{jk}^r c_{ir}^s+c_{ki}^r c_{jr}^s)=0
$$
for all $1\le i<j<k\le n,\; 1\le s\le n$. In general, we have to verify *all these equations*. Of course, there are many results, where you already know that the Jacobi identity must hold, e.g., if you construct your Lie algebra as a semidirect product of two other Lie algebras, or if your Lie brackets are given by commutator $[A,B]=AB-BA$ of matrices, which always satisfies the Jacobi identity.

Comment: Are you sure $i < j < k$ is enough? That would mean any "bracket" on a $2$-dimensional vector space is a Lie algebra?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, assuming skew-symmetry or $[x,x]=0$ of course. Indeed, every skew-symmetric bracket $[e_1,e_2]=\alpha e_1+\beta e_2$ in dimension two satisfies the Jacobi identity. For example, $[e_1,[e_1,e_2]]+[e_1,[e_2,e_1]]+[e_2,[e_1,e_1]]=0$ just follows from skew-symmetry.